# Console unreadable

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, console

I just installed a fresh copy of ArchLinux (2012-11-01) by following the [installation guide](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide).

When I boot into the new system, I am presented with a nice GRUB menu, then the loading messages. All this is fine until I get to the TTY login prompt which is completely illegible.

I tried running the `setfont` command but that changes the font to another illegible character set. I also tried setting the font in `/etc/vconsole.conf` but, again it is just gibberish, even though I can see that there is a change.

It appears no matter what font I set it to, it is not readable. I also verified that I am able to login to the system with my root password (if I look closely, I can almost make out the characters being displayed on the screen).

Here are the computer details:

```
Product Name: Compaq PC
Processor Type: Celeron
Processor Speed: 566/66 MHz
Memory Size: 512MB
System ROM Date: 02/11/00
System ROM Family: 686C3
Chasis Serial Number: 1X03DCV8N496
```

Is this an issue with the display card (since this is a very old computer) or misconfiguration?

**/etc/locale.conf**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

**/etc/vconsole.conf**

```
KEYMAP=us
FONT=
FONT_MAP=
```

Any ideas please?

**EDIT:**

```
sh-4.2# lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA Compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82810E DC-133 (CGC) Chipset Grapics Controller (rev 03)
sh-4.2# pacman -Ss xf86-video | grep installed
sh-4.2#
```

**EDIT 2:**

Interestingly, I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 and the same thing happens. Everything is fine when booting from CD, but as soon as I boot into the new OS, the console is unreadable.

Comment: Which graphics card do you have?

Comment: @grawity I'm using the built-in card.

Comment: Which doesn't tell us anything at all.

Comment: @grawity I know that doesn't say much. I thought the machine details above would give an idea. How can I tell what the chipset of the on-board card is?

Comment: @adaptive I deleted my answer since it wasn't helpful.  You can post that with "lspci | grep VGA" to give us an idea.  The other thing that would help is your driver, if any, you have installed "pacman -Ss xf86-video | grep installed".

Comment: I added the output of both commands. However, I'm running these commands from chroot (for hopefully obvious reasons).

Comment: The default intel driver may help (there is a legacy option as well, so that may end up better if the default fails), you can install with "pacman -S xf86-video-intel"  or if you want to see other options "pacman -Ss xf86-video | less"  Here is the summary of that section from the beginner's guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Install_a_video_driver

Comment: @nerdwaller: I believe adaptive is talking about the tty console, which does not use Xorg video drivers...

Comment: @grawity - Oops- I missed the main point of the question.  Thanks for pointing that out (and being nice about it)!